# Plotting a bar chart on World map using Rworldmap Package

Tags: r, rworldmap

I have a data set `df`, as below

```
Country             Rev2013     Rev2014    Rev2015
China               56.15       2.26      106.90            
United States       33.41999    138.12    96.62         
United Kingdom      32.93       28.74     101.86            
Brazil              20.42       48.17     118.24            
Indonesia           92.30       55.95     128.71        
Germany             5.02039     11.06     64.39
```

For the above data set I want to plot a bar chart using `rworldmap` something similar to [this](https://nzprimarysectortrade.wordpress.com/2011/10/02/let-r-fly-visualizing-export-data-using-r/).

Answer (score 0):

Spatial data is quite large topic, but to cut the idea short:

rworldmap has built in global shapemap:

```
require(rworldmap)
shapeMap <- getMap()
```

Next step would be understanding that Spatial Polygon object that you just made has similar structure to data frame.

You can add more columns to `shapeMap@data` where, obviously, all of the data assiciated with polygons is stored.

Such as:

```
shapeMap@data$Rev2013 <- df$Rev2013[match(shapeMap@data$NAME_SORT, df$Country)]
```

This is just to give you an idea how to start off with setting up data. Next step is plotting. Now here you have to make a choice - either with `spplot` or `ggplot2`.

Comment: @ val, thanks for your suggestion.I have used the code mentioned in the link example but i get a stacked plot instead of a bar chart. And I am not able to post the code used by me.